# Should I use a unnamed Timer or DispatchasyncAfter to delay something 1 time?

Tags: swift, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I can delay something in two ways (well maybe there are more ways):

```
   func delay(delay:Double, closure: @escaping ()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
    }

   //way 1:
    delay(delay: 1.0, closure: {
    })

   //way 2:
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false){ _ in 
    }
```

Is there any difference between those ways? Is way 1 better than way 2? I just want to add a delay of 1 second, which way should I use?

Comment: I prefer `asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .nanoseconds(value)) { ... }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` is a GCD method and hence it is better in performance. Though `NSTimer` is a much more flexible where you can stop or pause the timer but I don't think you can cancel the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` or at least you have to write a wrapper.

Though in your case repeats is false it won't effect flexibility.

Comment: Yes, I know I can stop a timer. However, I explicit stated an unnamed timer, which I think can not be stopped (on the other hand, I do not want to stop it anyway). I just want to execute something after 1 second. You sure dispatch is better in performance?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes dispatch is better

Comment: @J.Doe Yes for sure.